# Trix Editor Rails - Customizing

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, trix

I am using a trix editor such as  `<%= f.trix_editor :body, class: 'trix-content form-control', rows: 15 %>`

Currently the buttons are black and obviously translated english (as well as the alt texts).

How am I supposed to change the colors of the buttons? Everything Ive tried didn't seem to work.

Is there any way to provide german translations? I need my full application to be completely german.

Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the background color of the buttons with css.

```
trix-toolbar .trix-button-group button {
  background-color: green;
}
```

The button icons are images, so you would have to replace them in order to customize icon color, etc. For example, to remove the bold button icon with css:

```
trix-toolbar .trix-button-group button.trix-button--icon-bold::before {
  background-image: none;
}
```

You can change the button tooltips (for translation or otherwise) with javascript by referring to the `data-trix-attribute` for the button you would like to change. For example, to change the bold button where the `data-trix-attribute` is set to "bold" (due to browser inconsistencies, it is best to set both the `Trix.config.lang` and the element `title` attribute):

```
Trix.config.lang.bold = 'Really Bold';
document.querySelector('button[data-trix-attribute="bold"]').setAttribute('title', 'Really Bold');
```

Following snippet illustrates the various changes above.

```js
// hover over the now blank bold button in the toolbar to see the tooltip
Trix.config.lang.bold = 'Really Bold';
document.querySelector('button[data-trix-attribute="bold"]').setAttribute('title', 'Really Bold');
```

```css
trix-toolbar .trix-button-group button {
  background-color: green;
}

trix-toolbar .trix-button-group button.trix-button--icon-bold::before {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.1.1/trix.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.1.1/trix.js"></script>

<trix-editor></trix-editor>
```

Comment: This: `Trix.config.lang.bold = 'Really Bold';` does not work.

Comment: @MIA - appears that there are browser inconsistencies in how the tooltip is handled. See edited answer above for working cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm really late to the conversation but I was looking at doing this very issue this morning. There are solutions about replacing the icons that Trix [utilizes](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/blob/main/assets/trix/images/README.md) (Material Design Icons by Google). Someone has a really neat idea replacing them with FontAwesome icons.

These are SVG images so color cannot be changed. For my particular situation I used a webkit filter to change the color from black to gray:

```
trix-toolbar .trix-button--icon {
   -webkit-filter: invert(50%);
}
```

This should go in the application.scss. For a reason I have not tracked down yet, putting this in the actiontext.scss file is not working, even though it's being imported into the application.scss.